# Plotting phase of frequency response

Tags: dsp

I have a question on part A) iii [image: Question]

Here is what I have so far[image: Answers]

What I know is to get the overall phase you have to add the phases of the two frequency response H1 and H2, but I don't know how to get the phase of each frequency response. Any help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: So your book uses the fourier transform for discrete-time systems? cool.

Comment: Yeah but this is just a question on the phase of a frequency response. The fourier of this discrete time system is a sinc function I believe but I just need to know how to find the phase of the frequency response which I believe is the angle(4) + angle(e^(-j2w)). The angle of a constant is 0 but what is the angle of (e^(-j2w))?

Answer (score 1):

Since

$$H(e^{j\omega})=|H(e^{j\omega})|e^{j\phi(\omega)}$$

where \$\phi(\omega)\$ is the phase, you simply have

$$\phi(\omega)=-2\omega$$

which is the same as the phase of the first system, because the second system (ideal lowpass filter) has zero phase.